# Halcyon but in the future

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a good word like halcyon except in the future rather than halcyon's more commonly used reference to the past? Basically, a single word that will mean something like "future days will be better/peaceful".

Edit: The context would be "We're struggling now but _______ days are coming."

Comment: Also, I think that [utopian](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utopian) might come close, but not exact.  If it works for you, reply to this comment and I'll convert to an answer.

Comment: You wouldn't say "Past days were halcyon" so your example sentence doesn't quite fit what you're asking for.  Can you add a better example sentence?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Those were the halcyon days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Halcyon days](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/halcyon-days.html) says

> Fourteen days of calm weather were to be expected when the Halcyon was nesting - around the winter solstice, usually 21st or 22nd of December. The Halcyon days are generally regarded as beginning on the 14th or 15th of December.

Now while *Halcyon days* may refer to peaceful days of youth -- think of long, summer days, sitting on a swing or gathering flowers when you were, say, eight years old -- its primary meaning is closer to "peaceful."

It wouldn't be wrong to say:

> We're struggling now, but halcyon days are coming.

But the OP desires to use a different word (without a possible connotation of the past).

How about:

> We're struggling now, but the future looks bright.

If the struggle is because of arguments:

> We're fighting a lot now, but peaceful days are coming.

If the struggle is because of privation:

> We're often strapped/struggling, but flush/better days are coming.

or

> We're often poor, but days of plenty are coming.

Answer (score 0):

When US presidential candidates want to covey this idea they tend to use:

> **best**
>
> most excellently or suitably; with most advantage or success:
>   an opera role that best suits her voice.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/best)

As in:

[America's best days are yet to come.](http://ronaldreagan40.tumblr.com/post/55543469179/americas-best-days-are-yet-to-come-our)

Answer (score -1):

You're being [**optimistic**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+optimistic):

> hopeful and confident about the future.
>
> *"the optimistic mood of the sixties"*
>
> **synonyms:** hopeful, confident, positive, cheerful, cheery, sanguine, bright, buoyant, full of hope, bullish, Panglossian,
>   Pollyannaish; informalupbeat; of good cheer
>
> *"she felt optimistic about the future"*
>
> encouraging, promising, hopeful, reassuring, favorable, auspicious,
>   propitious
>
> *"the forecast is optimistic"*