# One word substitute for 'something worth waiting for'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word substitute for ***something worth waiting for***.

A typical usage of this word could be-

> I saw the trailer of Inception movie, and I found it _____.

While *good, awesome etc* tell us about the overall impression of the object, my focus is on the quality that makes it worthy to be waited for.

Another usage can be-

> The 2018 model of this car is so ______. So I will not buy a car this
>   year.

Comment: Maybe ***compelling*** works?

Comment: I thought of "tantalizing" ... yet it's not quite there

Comment: Very close to [Halcyon – but in the future](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342289/halcyon-but-in-the-future/342295#342295).

Comment: @Tom22 - You should offer that up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing this sentiment up in one word is a bit difficult. Perhaps "*propitious*" or "*promising*" to imply that the inherent appeal of the object and justifying the wait time.

> **Propitious:** favorably disposed; tending to favor.
>
> *The business proposal seemed to be a **propitious** venture.*

or

> **Promising**: full of promise; likely to succeed or to yield good results.
>
> *The preview made the upcoming book appear **promising** for fans of the author's previous works.*

*Definitions from Merriam-Webster

Comment: I was just about to say that. +1. It would be nice to add some definition and example sentences and improve this answer.

Comment: Good point, @NVZ. 

propitious: favorably disposed; tending to favor. 

The business proposal seemed to be a propitious venture.

promising: full of promise; likely to succeed or to yield good results.

The preview made the upcoming book appear promising for fans of the author's previous works.

*Definitions from Merriam-Webster

Comment: You must [edit] your answer and add that info there. :)